# Accessing Objects inside Array inside JSON object using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sqlite

I have an encoded JSON object that stores an array of objects that I wish to iterate through in order to input into a database. The Result object is similar to as follows:

```
{
    "customers": [
        {
            "customer": {
                "id":"1",
                "customerName":"Customer Alpha",
                "customerID":" custA",
                "customerAddress":" Alpha Way",
                "customerCity":" Alpha",
                "customerState":" AL",
                "customerZip":"91605"
            }
        },
        {
            "customer": {
                "id":"2",
                "customerName":"Customer Beta",
                "customerID":" CustB",
                "customerAddress":" Beta Street",
                "customerCity":" Beta",
                "customerState":" BE",
                "customerZip":"91605"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to be able to input each field into the database, but the code I have inputs undefined into the database for everything. What is the proper way to access the variables stored in each field inside the array?

Here's what I'm using so far which doesn't work:

```
function insertCustomer(customerName, customerID, customerAddress, customerCity, customerState, customerZip) {
db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Customers (customerName, customerID, customerAddress, customerCity, customerState, customerZip) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [customerName, customerID, customerAddress, customerCity, customerState, customerZip], CountReturns);
    });
};

        $.ajax({
      url      : 'http://webserver/retrieveDatabase.php',
      dataType : 'json',
      type     : 'get',
      success  : function(Result){
        alert(Result.customers);
        for (var i = 0, len = Result.customers.length; i < len; ++i) {
          var customer = Result.customers[i];
          insertCustomer(customer.customerName, customer.customerID, customer.customerAddress, customer.customerCity, customer.customerState, customer.customerZip);
        }
      }
    });
```

The alert responds with a series of [object Object]s.

Comment: Use `console.log` instead of alert (and check your browser console for the output). `Result.customers` is an array of objects, that's why alert shows what you're seeing.

Comment: From your sample data above, it looks like the customer name, for example, would be accessed using: `Result.customers[i].customer.customerName`. Your code only uses `Result.customers[i].customerName`. The name of the temp variable `customer` hides this subtlety.

Comment: @JimCote, your answer is not an "Answer" so I can't bump it up, but after three days of bashing my skull in, YOUR comment saved me!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change

```
var customer = Result.customers[i];
```

to

```
var customer = Result.customers[i].customer;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the JSON object like:

```
for(var key in Result["customers"]) {
   // examples
   console.log( Result[key].customer );
   console.log( Result[key]["customer"] );
   console.log( Result[key]["customer"].customerID );
}
```